# elasticsearch - how to monitor fielddata vs node RAM

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS, 8GB RAM, multi node cluster.

We are reviewing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html

and have a few questions.

1) Other than the breakers, how do we see approaching max-out of fielddata RAM ?  (The stats in `/_stats/fielddata?fields=*` , like `memory_size`, don't show 'available_memory')

2) When we run `/_stats/fielddata?fields=*`, we see `"primaries"` and `"total"`, which is fine. But what is the total a total of?  It appears to be `memory_size * number of nodes`, (but that doesn't make sense to us).

3) We moved from nodes with 4GB RAM to nodes with 8GB RAM, yet we feel like the avail RAM (on stock elasticsearch.yml) for fielddata did not double. Is that a fair conclusion?

The essential thing we want to monitor is: How close are we to maxing RAM... but we don't see what to measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not maxing RAM, but HEAP. ES is using both Heap memory (from the JVM) and, also, RAM (as file data cache).

To see how much heap your nodes are using, this is the command to use: `GET /_nodes/stats/jvm`, which will output something like

```
     "jvm": {
        "timestamp": 1447790529519,
        "uptime_in_millis": 84853,
        "mem": {
           "heap_used_in_bytes": 311374768,
           "heap_used_percent": 14,
           "heap_committed_in_bytes": 2112618496,
```

You need `100 * heap_used_in_bytes / heap_committed_in_bytes` and resulting a percentage of usage. Or simply ysing `heap_used_percent`. For the actual RAM usage, use your OS reports for that or `GET /_nodes/stats/os`.

For `fielddata` you can get statistics **per node** using `GET /_nodes/stats/indices/fielddata`

Comment: Thank you!  So we should watch : heap_used_percent  , cool.  What is a problem? 90? 80? 99?

Comment: The heap is configured to be freed at 75%. So, if you notice the heap **staying** above 75% then your cluster might have a problem. In your previous post I was telling you that the heap usage goes up and down, in a saw-tooth pattern. I'd suggest looking at that post where I provided some links about heap usage.